# Allowing editing only certain fields in SharePoint list

Tags: list

I have a SharePoint list where users submit the data using a Microsoft form. After submission, I want to have mangers to approve and comment on the submission before it goes to a higher level of management and a PDF is generated with the approval and comments. Is there a way to allow manger to see the submission but only can change certain fields but not the original submission?!

Thank you

P.S. if it’s not possible what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Please tag with which version of Sharepoint you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SharePoint does not provide column-level security.  But it is still possible to achieve your goal with a little creativity.

You didn't specify which version of SharePoint you are using, so I will give you a recommendation assuming SharePoint Online.  If You post that you are using something different, I will adjust this accordingly.

You can lock the list down so that none of the managers have edit rights to your list at all.
Then create a dedicated user account specific for this purpose that **does** have edit access to the list.
Then create a PowerApp or use the new Flow UI to show them the item fields for approval, and put editable fields on the form only for the values you want them to submit.  Create a custom connection for your Power App or Flow that logs in with the dedicated user account you created earlier.  This app can then save the values the manager entered.

Another possible solution is by having two separate lists, one that is a "master" list with all the fields on it.  The second list has a unique lookup column to the first, and a copy of the two fields you want editable.
A Flow configured for the "master" list ensures creating an item in the second list with the Lookup column pointing to the item that triggered the Flow, and potentially notifies the managers.
The managers can edit the fields in the second list, but have no contribute rights to the "master list".  Then a Flow configured on the second list copies the values from those fields back to the master list whenever a change is made.

Comment: Thank you, I am using SharePoint Online. And I am thinking of initiating a flow once a new list is submitted. So for example if the list has four fields: Assigned to, progress, approved by  , comments and the first two fields will be from a MS Form submitted by users, then the manager will have to complete the other two fields without being able to edit the first two. is it doable my friend?

Comment: If they have edit access to an item on the list, there is nothing that stops them from editing any field on that item.  SharePoint does NOT have column-level security.  The only way to truly stop them is to lock them out of editing all fields, and have a separate form that allows them to enter the two fields you want to allow with a Flow (or other automated secured service) that copies those values to the actual list item.

Comment: I edited the answer to give you another option that uses two separate lists, one which none of the managers can edit that has all fields values, and a second list that has a copy of just the fields you want to them to edit.  And Flows to keep the two lists in sync.

Comment: Got you, but how the flow that allows the manager to complete the list would be implemented? I am thinking of having an excel sheet with protected cells so that mangers can save that excel file and a list can be updated. If there are other solutions that would be wonderful.

Comment: Both of the solutions presented would be less complex that putting an Excel spreadsheet into the mix.  At a high level, you need to lock the permissions on your primary list so that none of your users can edit directly, then you build some custom entry point where they can enter the two values that you need and your Flow then uses a privileged account to save those values back to the secure list.

Comment: Ok. So if I go to the master list idea, what you are suggesting is to creat power app form where only the fields that I want mangers to change are editable then share the form with them right ?

Comment: Yes, then your App uses a user connection to that Does have edit permissions on the list, so it can save those fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the box feature to set permission restriction on editing column in SharePoint Online.

However, some third-party tools or java scripts may achieve this feature. Here are some threads for your reference:

[Column level permissions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/27f274f7-b527-45f3-ac9d-c2da8f8bfa71/column-level-permissions?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

[SharePoint Online / Office 365 - Column Level Security - Issues And Possible Options](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online-office-365-column-level-security-iss/)

For more details, please refer the below thread, similar question is discussed :

[Restrict edit access to certain columns in a SharePoint List](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/restrict-edit-access-to-certain-columns-in-a/b5b74be6-4301-4e34-ba97-9fa8b36edb9d)

**Simple, possible way to handle this**

Using the scripting code, get the current user and based on the user hide the particular column.